# How generate binary variables without duplicated ID rows

Tags: r

I have this data frame :

```
  >df
ID  X1 X2 X3
IX  0   0  1
IX  1   1  0
IY  0   0  1
IZ  1   0  0
IZ  0   1  0
```

I need to create  a no duplicated data frame that have unique `ID` and 
as result it should take in consideration all binary elements

In other word , the result should be :

```
ID  X1 X2 X3
IX  1   1  1
IY  0   0  1
IZ  1   1  0
```

I tried to use the `duplicated` function, but it just delete ID rows without having consideration to binary values and it doesn't give the needed result.

What should I do please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate(df[2:4], df[1], sum)`

Comment: Not sure if it would ever happen but you might need to handle the special case where the sum of the column is greater than 1 , as 1 evaluates TRUE but 2 (3,4... etc.) evaluates to FALSE in R.

Comment: Use `max` instead of `sum`.